# GAE SDK 1.9.5 and an InvalidCertificateException

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

Trying to import testbed from GAE SDK 1.95 with Python2.7.8  on osX Maverics 10.9.5
and I'm getting a InvalidCertificateException error.

```
    from google.appengine.ext import testbed   
  File "/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/testbed/__init__.py", line 120, in <module>  
    from google.appengine.api import urlfetch_stub   
  File "/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/urlfetch_stub.py", line 34, in <module>  
    _fancy_urllib_InvalidCertException = fancy_urllib.InvalidCertificateException  
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'InvalidCertificateException'
```

I looked at the fancy_url module and the InvalidCertificateException class is there, so I don't understand why it's not importing.

Apparently others have had the same error, so I attempt to correct it by deleting: **urlfetch_cacerts.txt** AND **cacerts.txt** from:

```
GoogleAppEngineLauncher/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngineDefault.bundle/Content‌​s/Resources/google_appengine/lib/cacerts/
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Apparently the GAE installer creates a nested directory, this was fixed by copying the contents in:

```
cd /usr/local/google_appengine/lib
cp fancy_urllib/fancy_urllib/__init__.py fancy_urllib/__init__.py
```

This is how the module is incorrectly structured, it looks like these 2 **init**.py files are duplicate:

```
/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/fancy_urllib/__init__.py   # this file is empty
/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/fancy_urllib/fancy_urllib/__init__.py # this file contains the functions.
```

FIXED THE ERROR

Comment: Rather than copying, I think a better option is to create a link, so assuming you are in `cd /usr/local/google_appengine/lib`, then do  `ln -f -r -s ./fancy_urllib/fancy_urllib/__init__.py -t fancy_urllib`