# App Engine python local unit test urlfetch_stub.py fancy_urllib module has no attribute 'InvalidCertificateException'

Tags: python, testing, google-app-engine-python, urlfetch

I'm using linux with google-cloud-sdk-app-engine-python package installed version 196.0.0-0.

I try to create local unit test, following reference from [1].

```
class ViewsTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = application.test_client()
        self.client.testing = True
        self.testbed = testbed.Testbed()
        self.testbed.activate()
        self.testbed.init_urlfetch_stub()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.testbed.deactivate()
```

add PYTHONPATH environment variable:

```
export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine:/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib:/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/yaml/lib"
```

then I try to run it.

```
$ python test_views.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_views.py", line 6, in <module>
    from google.appengine.ext import testbed
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/testbed/__init__.py", line 130, in <module>
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch_stub
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/urlfetch_stub.py", line 32, in <module>
_fancy_urllib_InvalidCertException = fancy_urllib.InvalidCertificateException
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'InvalidCertificateException'
```

I have read this similar thread [2].

But I checked, the path of fancy_lib has been fixed.

```
$ find /usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/fancy_urllib/
/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/fancy_urllib/
/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/fancy_urllib/__init__.pyc
/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/fancy_urllib/fancy_urllib
/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/fancy_urllib/fancy_urllib/__init__.pyc
/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/fancy_urllib/fancy_urllib/__init__.py
/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/fancy_urllib/__init__.py
```

I have tried to add fancy_urllib to PYTHONPATH

```
export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine:/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib:/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/yaml/lib:/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/fancy_urllib"
```

But still failed.

any clue?

thank you.

[1]https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/localunittesting

[2][GAE SDK 1.9.5 and an InvalidCertificateException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27114470/gae-sdk-1-9-5-and-an-invalidcertificateexception)

Comment: I got this in CI after doing nothing, still works on local machine. Have you found the solution?

Answer (score 3):

If you see the file length of **init**.py is '0' and if there is sub folder with the same name (i.e. lib/fancy_urllib/fancy_urllib), then copy both files (.py, and .pyc) of the sub folder to upper folder.  That worked for me.